# Populating pulldowns from multiple tables data entry page

Tags: php, mysql, select

I needed to add another pulldown to my data entry page and figured out a way to present the date in both tables, but it's doubling up in each one, i.e. the Artist pulldown is showing:

Add N to X
Add N to X
Air
Air
Amon Tobin
Amon Tobin
Etc.

And the Contributor pulldown is showing:

Joe Blow
Joe Blow
Dick Wad
Dick Wad
Etc.

Here's where I doubled up table data:

```
SELECT artists.id, artists.artists_name, contributors.id, contributors.contributors_name FROM artists, contributors ORDER BY artists.artists_name, contributors.contributors_name";
```

And here it is on context:

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO news (artistid, contributorid, title, blog_entry, rating) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['artistid'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['contributorid'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['title'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['blog_entry'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['rating'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_em, $em);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $em) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "add_post.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

mysql_select_db($database_em, $em);
$query_listPosts = "SELECT artists.id, artists.artists_name, contributors.id, contributors.contributors_name FROM artists, contributors ORDER BY artists.artists_name, contributors.contributors_name"; 
$listPosts = mysql_query($query_listPosts, $em) or die(mysql_error());
$row_listPosts = mysql_fetch_assoc($listPosts);
$totalRows_listPosts = mysql_num_rows($listPosts);
?>
```

Here's how I'm presenting it in the page:

```
<p>
<label for="artistid">Artist:</label>
</p>
<p><select name="artistid">
<option value="0">Not registered</option>
<?php
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_listPosts['id']?>"><?php echo $row_listPosts['artists_name']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_listPosts = mysql_fetch_assoc($listPosts));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($listPosts);
if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($listPosts, 0);
  $row_listPosts = mysql_fetch_assoc($listPosts);
}
?>
</select></p>
<p>
<label for="contributorid">Contributor:</label>
</p>
<p><select name="contributorid">
<option value="0">Not registered</option>
<?php
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_listPosts['id']?>"><?php echo $row_listPosts['contributors_name']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_listPosts = mysql_fetch_assoc($listPosts));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($listPosts);
if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($listPosts, 0);
  $row_listPosts = mysql_fetch_assoc($listPosts);
}
?>
</select></p>
```

Although I can work with this doubling up for now it'll become an issue when I add more pulldowns to my data entry page, so any ideas how I can fix this so that each pulldown just has the one instance of data instead of doubling would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I'm taking a look at the pages you provided, thanks, although this update is definitely something I'd feel more comfortable performing after the site I'm trying to put together is functioning at least close to where I need it to be. In fact this data entry page is one of the last elements I need to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by your query. You are joining 2 tables together that do not have relationship, so it is creating multiple rows, matching up `artists` and `contributors`, and the `id`'s are merging.

I have created this issue at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7962/2/0

Here is what I suggest-

Change the 1 query to 2 queries, and to simplify the code, change from a `do-while` loop to a `while()` loop

Queries-

```
$query_Artists = "SELECT id, artists_name FROM artists ORDER BY artists_name";
$query_Contributors = "SELECT id,contributors_name FROM contributors ORDER BY contributors_name"; 
$listArtists = mysql_query($query_Artists, $em) or die(mysql_error());
$listContributors = mysql_query($query_Contributors, $em) or die(mysql_error());
```

Drop downs-

```
<p>
<label for="artistid">Artist:</label>
</p>
<p><select name="artistid">
<option value="0">Not registered</option>
<?php
if(mysql_num_rows($listArtists) > 0) {
while ($artist_dropdown = mysql_fetch_assoc($listArtists)) {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $artist_dropdown['id']?>"><?php echo $artist_dropdown['artists_name']?></option>
<?php
}
}
?>
</select></p>
<p>
<label for="contributorid">Contributor:</label>
</p>
<p><select name="contributorid">
<option value="0">Not registered</option>
<?php
if(mysql_num_rows($listContributors) > 0) {
while ($contributors_dropdown = mysql_fetch_assoc($listContributors)) {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $contributors_dropdown['id']?>"><?php echo $contributors_dropdown['contributors_name']?></option>
<?php
}
}
?>
</select></p>
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. It didn't work at first until I spotted this line which was easily fixed:

<option value="<?php echo $contributors_dropdown['id']?>"><?php echo $contributors_dropdown['contributors_name']?></option>

Comment: I have edited my answer to correct that line. I was copying/pasting, and missed that one. Glad it worked for you.